# Where do I find the 7 digit pin code to reprogram my 2005 Ford f-150 xl 4.2 litre,

Tags: key, code, program

I need the chipped key code or PIN code that I think is seven digits long for my 2005 Ford f150 XL 4.2 l rear wheel drive so I can reprogram my key to the truck because I unplugged my immobilizer and now it's locked me out I have the little computer to do it I just need the 7 digit code and the dealership won't give it to me I don't need any retarded answers I just need to know the location or how to find the code please and thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What did the dealership tell you why they wouldn't give it to you? In cases like that if you provide them your ID and registration, they'll usually do it. Maybe a fee, but there shouldn't be an issue. BTW, not trying to be "retarded", but we don't usually answer questions like this because there is a high probability someone asking the question isn't on the up and up. Just saying.

Comment: They said because I didn't buy the truck there ,that even if I gave them the vin number they couldn't look it up,I know there's a sticker or imprint somewhere on my truck that has it,and btw,I feel like you know how I could find it,but just are not gonna tell me 

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you've bought the truck there or not. If they won't help you, there's more than likely another Ford dealership not too far away you can check with. Like I said, provide them the registration and your ID proving you own it and they should be able to give you the information you're looking for.